# How to use a required data annotation for a list of textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form with multiple values for a custom question. The idea being a user can make their own custom question with custom answers. One of the properties of the Model object is a list of objects:

```
public class CustomQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string QuestionName{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomQuestionAnswer> Answers { get; set; }

}

public class CustomQuestionAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

}
```

Now I have this in razor which works to create the answers (I have omitted the rest of the question):

```
foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
{
    if (answer.IsActive)
    {
        <div class="form-group answer">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Hidden("answers[" + count + "].Id", answer.Id)
                @Html.TextBox("answers[" + count + "].Answer", answer.Answer, new { @class = "form-control" })
                validation code will go here
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.CheckBox("answers[" + count + "].IsActive", answer.IsActive)
           </div>
       </div>
       count++;
    }
}
```

Now everything is working fine and saving to the database, except the data validation is not working. I have the data validation messages working for the CustomQuestion's QuestionName (so I know it is not an issue of jquery loading properly), but not for the answers. I have tried putting these lines in the razor form:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => answer.Answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("Answers[" + count + "].Answer", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

But neither works. Also, when I click on the save button, I get this error message in the browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ({"Answers[0].Answer":["The Answer field is required."]})
```

Any ideas as to what I need for the validation code?

Comment: If you using ViewModel why don't you use `ValidationMessageFor`, `TextBoxFor` and  `CheckBoxFor` helpers? They will generate right markup for you

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is (or contains) an indexed collection, it is better to use a `for`-loop along with fully specified variables and with `...For` helpers, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
{
    if (Model.Answers[i].IsActive)
    {
        <div class="form-group answer">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Answers[i].Id)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Answers[i].Answer, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Answers[i].Answer, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Answers[i].IsActive)
           </div>
       </div>
    }
}
```

It may seem awkward or even unnecessary to keep referencing the full `Model.Answers[i]` everywhere, but MVC uses reflection on these expressions to come up with the full names to output, which are needed for Model Binding to succeed, and also for pairing it with ModelState which uses the same object structure.
The use of a temporary or helper variable such as your `answer` will cause MVC to not be able to do this anymore, and then the burden becomes your own.

Comment: I cant edit it, but there is an extra quotation mark in the line `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Answers[i].IsActive")`

Answer (score 2):

You should use strongly typed helpers if you have ViewModel. To make right binging you should use `for` loop instead of `foreach`.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model.Answers[i].IsActive)
    {
        <div class="form-group answer">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Answers[i].Id)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Answers[i].Answer, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => x => Model.Answers[i].Answer, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.CheckBox(x => Model.Answers[i].IsActive)
           </div>
       </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Validation you can use this code :

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => answer.Answer,null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Please check it and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

you can customize you message in the model
like:

```
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "You need a valid email adress")]
        [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "the length of an Email address must be at least 40 chars")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string CurrentMail { get; set; }
```

and then you make a simple

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentMail)
```

instead Of `@Html.TextBox(m => m.CurrentMail)`